# CGRectsIntersects without two images colliding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue at the moment. I am making a game. When two imageViews collide the game will end. I am using CGRECTIntersects rect to detect if the two images collide.

The issue is that when i restart the game the collision will happen when in fact the two images have not actually touched one another?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank you

-(void)collision {

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(object.frame, object2.frame)) {
    object.hidden=YES;
    object2.hidden=YES;
    retry.hidden=NO;
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

}

/- (void)viewDidLoad
{

```
retry.hidden=YES;


timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(object2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



objectSpeed1 = CGPointMake(3.0, 2.0);

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

/- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender {

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"restart" sender:sender];
```

}

-(void)object2 {

```
object2.center = CGPointMake(object2.center.x + object2.x, object2.center.y + objectspeed1.y);

if (object2.center.x > 310 || object2.center.x < 10) {
    objectspeed1.x = - objectspeed1.x;
}
if (object2.center.y > 558 || object2.center.y < 10) {
    objectspeed1.y = - objectspeed1.y;
}
```

Comment: how do you expect us to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: seriously: how do you think we are able to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: sorry i am new to stack overflow

Comment: and still the question is: how do you expect us to help you if you don't provide your faulty code. You can answer as often as you want that you are new to stackoverflow, as long as you don't provide your code, you shouldn't expect any help.

Comment: ok so i am using to viewcontrollers when an image collides with one another a button retry appears which when clicked brings the user back to orignal viewcontroller where they can click start and the game restarts but sometimes the images collide without actually colliding here is the code for the collisiong between the two images.

Comment: again: how do you expect us to fix your code, if you don't provide it?

Comment: -(void)collision {
    
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(object1.frame, object2.frame)) {
        object1.hidden=YES;
        object2.hidden=YES;
        retry.hidden=NO;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
  
    
}

Comment: please add it to the question. and you will have to add any code dealing with the frames and positions.

Comment: how do i add multiple lines of code and make it look nice for you to read apologies

Comment: how about pasting the code in, selecting it and press the source code button?

Comment: i put all the code related to this up there

Comment: how about formatting your codes? and know you should tell us, when collision is called. and that should actually be the answer, as object's and object2's frame surly aren't set up that time.

Comment: So the frame of the objects are not set properly when the game reloads is it?

Comment: listen Ray: stackoverflow is a site for professional coders and those who aims to be professional, so either you start to act professional and give us the codes you need help with or you should consider to find yourself another community. It is very annoying that you ask for help with codes that you don't provide. where are the codes when you restart a game?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider this case on the code. You can check if image views are on their start position or they came to this position from another. It's enough to keep `BOOL` property on viewcontroller's class like this:

```
// ViewController.m

@interface ViewController ()

@property (readonly) BOOL isStarted;

@end

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _isStarted = NO;

    // Make some preparations for app's needs

    _isStarted = YES;
}

@end
```

`_isStarted` is a flag which shows whether viewcontroller is ready to handle the data.

```
if(_isStarted) {
    // Analyze image views' frame
}
else {
    // Do nothing
}
```